# Git - error while pushing code to remote repository

Tags: git

I have a local git branch "trustly-payment" and I also have remote repository by the same name. When I try to push the code from local branch "trustly-payment" to remote branch "trustly-payment" I always get the error::

```
git push origin/trustly-payment trustly-payment
fatal: 'origin/trustly-payment' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Note 1): The remote repository exists there.

Note 2): When I push using PhpStorm, it works fine.

Note 3): Correct access right is in place otherwise PhpStorm would not have been able to push successfully.

Comment: `git push --help`.  Look at the error message: it is telling you that it thinks that `origin/trustly-payment` is a repository. You know it is not a repository, it is a refspec, so try to think about how you might have made a mistake in the parameters to `git push` to make git think that.

Comment: It seems like the console is taking `origin/trustly-payment` as the name of the remote. Try just `git push origin trustly-payment`

Comment: @DCruz22 : I think the command provided by you will push the code to origin master.

Comment: @D555 the last part of the command is specifying the branch in which you will push the commit, in this case is `trustly-payment`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. You want to do

```
git push origin trustly-payment
```

If that would not push to trustly-payment on remote because of non-standard configuration you did, you might want to use a refspec like

```
git push origin trustly-payment:trustly-payment
```